# IntelliJ Git rebase error

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have the following situation:

1. A branch `master`;
2. A topic branch `x` off of `master`;
3. I have made a commit to `master`, and I would like to have this available in `x` as well. It is my understanding that I have to rebase `x` on `master`.

This is what I do:

1. Checkout the `x` branch: `VCS -> Git -> Branches -> Local branches -> x -> Checkout`;
2. Go to `VCS -> Git -> Rebase -> Select master in onto`.
3. Click Rebase.

At this point an error shows up telling me to check the VC console for details. This is what the console shows:

```
23:59:22.839: git rebase -i -v -m refs/heads/master
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

There are no pending changes in any branch anywhere. Everything is committed (and pushed to Bitbucket if that makes any difference). Am I doing this right? How can I rebase my branch on `master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because you have unstaged changes, stash them or commit them will allow you to do the rebase command.

**BUT, I think what you are doing here is totally wrong.**

first, you are not supposed to commit on a master branch, you should commit on the topic branch and merge/rebase it with/on the master branch.

second, according to what you want to do, it's rebasing master on x, not rebasing x on master.

so you should

```
1, checkout master  --> git checkout master
2, rebase on x      --> git rebase x
3, do some merge job
4, continue the rebase --> git rebase --continue
```

btw, you should read [pro-git](http://git-scm.com/book), it's free and it's a very good book.

**EDIT:**

After reading the url you post, I think I had some misunderstanding here.

say you have this:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* c85d8bd (HEAD, master) dev on master again
| * 431a9c6 (topic) dev on topic
|/
* 4ad2cc4 dev on master
* d576e88 init
```

and here we are going to try two rebase commands:

**1, rebase master on topic**

```
git checkout master
git rebase topic
```

this will make the history look like this:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* 03021da (HEAD, master) dev on master again
* 431a9c6 (topic) dev on topic
* 4ad2cc4 dev on master
* d576e88 init
```

**2, rebase topic on master**

```
git checkout topic
git rebase master
```

your history will be like:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* adc93f1 (HEAD, topic) dev on topic
* c85d8bd (master) dev on master again
* 4ad2cc4 dev on master
* d576e88 init
```

it's all about you want whom to be on whom:)

and I'm remembering this in this way:

```
merge with <branch>
rebase on <branch>
```

but there is an exception, while using:

```
git rebase --onto
```

you can find these details in [pro-git](http://git-scm.com/book)'s Chapter 3.6

Comment: But I don't have any unstaged changes. The changes list is empty for every branch. Are you sure your steps will do what I want? I want to what is described here: http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/the-magical-and-not-harmful-rebase/ - it says to use `git rebase master` there. Any idea why I that error shows up if no changes show up?

Comment: Thanks, but I know those. I still get that error with nothing available to commit, any idea why that is?

Comment: If you are sure there are no changes that are not commited, maybe you can try the `git reset --hard HEAD` command.

Comment: well, I guess I wasn't sure. There were none showing up in the IDE, but when running `git status` in the command line, apparently there were some deleted files. Don't rely so much on the IDE I guess, eh? That command fixed it and I was able to rebase, thanks for your help.